# Permissions on my mac are messed right up

Tags: macos, permissions

Whenever I use one of my ec2 instances (amazon) and I'm doing any programming on that end, it seems like I can run any command without having any need for sudo, e.g. `npm install` (using node)

But on my local dev using my macbook, I have to `sudo` almost everything I do, which is really annoying because it makes my `ide` not able to do half the helpful things it should be able to do.

How might I reset my permissions on everything so that I don't need to sudo everything.

Running OS X 10.11.3 Thanks.

Comment: Are you logged in on your Amazon instance as root? Why can't you sudo su which will leave you logged in as root and then do commands from there? Or run your ide under sudo?

Comment: @Darius I feel like this shouldn't be, and isn't the solution to my issue, sure I can live as the root user all day every day, but like I said, that isn't the answer. Also no, I'm logged in as a base user

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to remember is that while annoying, ***it helps keep you secure***. There are many ways that a remote attacker can mess you right up even more if any `sudo` command goes unprompted but I'll get off my soapbox now.

What you can do is edit your `sudoers` file with the command **`sudo visudo`**.

> *SIDE NOTE:*  Please make sure to use `visudo` and not `vi` to edit the sudoers file. As the man page explains:
>
> **visudo** edits the sudoers file in a safe fashion, analogous to vipw(8).
>   **visudo** locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits,
>   provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.  If the
>   sudoers file is currently being edited you will receive a message to
>   try again later ...
>
> **visudo** parses the sudoers file after the edit and will not > save the changes if there is a syntax error. This is critcal to avoid getting 
>   locked out

Okay, now that you are editing the sudoers file, search for this line

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

and change it to this

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Save the file and you should now not be prompted for a password when using the sudo command.

*Caveat Emptor!*